Component only has access to array's old state
I'm working with React and I have a table that users can add and delete rows from. The table is made with an array of components. Each component/row has a trash can icon that when clicked executes the delete row function. It would seem that each component only has access to the old state of the array/table, and so deleting doesn't work correctly. Any ideas how I could fix this issue?
An example of a component in the useState array that makes up this table:
<Row
  className={className}
  columns={columns}
  text={text}
  key={key}
  keyProp={key}
  deleteFunction={() => removeRow(key)}
/>

The delete function that is a prop for every row/component in the array:
function removeRow(key) {
  setMeals(meals.filter(i => i.props.keyProp !== key));
  // This should only remove the one row which had its trash can icon clicked.
  // If there's 10 rows and you click the trash can for row 4, rows 4-10
  // will be deleted.
  // If you click the trash can for row 7, rows 7-10 will be deleted and so on.
}


You should really be using a functional state update, e.g. setMeals(meals => meals.filter(meal => meal.props.keyProp !== key)); to correctly reference the current state, but I suspect you also have some odd Javascript closure issue. Can you [edit] the post to share a complete [mcve] of the code rendering Row and holds whatever this meals state is?

@Drew Reese "You should really be using a functional state update, e.g. setMeals(meals => meals.filter(meal => meal.props.keyProp !== key));" This is basically what worked for me but I'm not sure why. Do you know?

Yes, it's generally caused by Javascript Closures where the removeRow callback handler, or rather the deleteFunction prop isn't updated in the Row component or wherever it ultimately lands and is used that doesn't recapture, or re-enclose, the updated meals state when it updates. This is why I asked for a more complete [mcve] so we could see the complete path from const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]) through to where the handler is called. Does this make sense?

Give this a try, I am confident it will resolve the issue.
function removeRow(key) {
// This updates the previous meal array whenever there's a removal in the meal array
 setMeals((prevMeals) => {
    return prevMeals.filter((meal) => meal.props.keyProp !== key)
})

Also, improve your Delete function as shown below:
<Row className={className} columns={columns} text={text} key={key} keyProp={key} deleteFunction={() => removeRow.bind(null, key)} />


As others pointed out, your problem is likely elsewhere in your code. Using a functional update is preferred, but I don't think filter is the right choice to remove a known index from an array. Here's a functioning demo for you to work from -


function App() {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(Array.from("ABCDEF"))
  
  const removeRow = index => event => {
    setRows(prev => prev.slice(0, index).concat(prev.slice(index + 1)))
  }

  return rows.map((key, index) =>
    <div key={key} onClick={removeRow(index)} children={key} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
div ~ div { margin-top: 0.5rem; }
div > div { cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid silver; padding: 0.5rem }
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



It is a common need to immutably remove an element from an array. You will likely benefit from separating this logic from your component to make it reusable in other parts of your program -


function removeAt(arr, index) {
  return arr.slice(0, index).concat(arr.slice(index + 1))
}


function App() {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(Array.from("ABCDEF"))
  
  const removeRow = index => event => {
    setRows(prev => removeAt(prev, index))
  }

  return rows.map((key, index) =>
    <div key={key} onClick={removeRow(index)} children={key} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
div ~ div { margin-top: 0.5rem; }
div > div { cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid silver; padding: 0.5rem }
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>





Using Array.filter is the standard method for removing elements from an array and returning a new array reference for React. I don't know why anyone would use two Array.slice calls and one Array.concat call over a single .filter. @DrewReese

Let's ask another question, why would anyone use an entire .filter over two .slice and a single .concat?
Or speaking by our intentions, why would anyone scan an entire array when the target element's position is already known?  ‍♀️



program
array size
comparisons
function calls




filter
100
100
100


filter
1,000
1,000
1,000


filter
10,000
10,000
10,000


--
--
--
--


removeAt
100
0
3


removeAt
1,000
0
3


removeAt
10,000
0
3



Benchmark show removeAt performing ~5x faster than filter for array sizes N=[100..10000] -



program
array size
ops/s
+/-




filter
100
289,000
64% slower


removeAt
100
804,000
278% faster


--
--
--
--


filter
1,000
22,000
83% slower


removeAt
1,000
129,000
586% faster


--
--
--
--


filter
10,000
2,100
87% slower


removeAt
10,000
16,000
761% faster




There's also really no reason to abstract a removeAt utility when the functional Array methods can be called directly inline. What is gained in doing so? @DrewReese

Programming languages are ignorant of our intentions. Naming things gives us power over them. We can reuse named functions in other parts of our program. In the words of Gerald Jay Sussman, if you have the name of a spirit, you have power over it.
